# Javascript Bookmarklet IE8

Tags: javascript

Has anyone an idea why the following JavaScript codes is working without any problems on Firefox and was working on IE7 as well but not on IE8 anymore? I have not a clue and I appreciate any hint :-)

I have added the code as a favorite item to my Internet Explorer. So a click on this favorite item should execute the code and load a JavaScript file which is located on my server and append it to the website which is currently loaded in the browser.

```
javascript:void((
function(){
    var%20e=document.createElement('script');
    e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    e.setAttribute('src','http://www.mydomain.com/js/bookmarklet.js');
    document.body.appendChild(e)
}
)())
```

Thanks for any help and happy coding :-)

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: No, I don't get any error message in the console.

Comment: Does the page you are adding to run in quirks mode or in standards mode? You can find out with IE developer tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to add a script to a web page would be:

```
var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
scriptNode.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptNode);
```

Please, try that, it works in IE8.

Comment: You are welcome! Always nice to help fellow scripter in distress :) Please, vote my answer up. It helps the reputation too.